# HEIC/HEIF changed to jpeg without metadata at upload

Tags: ios, node.js, heif

I have a small webapp that runs on a server intended for use in a setting without reliable internet access (i.e., the app can't depend on outside resources during production).  The purpose of the app is simply to upload image files, read the metadata, and categorize them in the right location on the disk.  Up until recently there was no problem with this process, then I noticed that some of the files did not have all of the metadata attached (specifically the creation date).  Upon further inspection, it appears that these are files that were shot on my iPhone as HEIC/HEIF photos and uploaded directly to the webpage from the phone.

Due to the design of the webapp, the filename of the uploaded file is shown on the page.  Every time an HEIC photo is uploaded it displays the filename as ending in .jpeg.

I've had a hard time finding good documentation on this, but it sounds like the default for the iPhone at this point is to convert HEIC files to jpeg if it looks like they are transferring to a location that may not be able to read them.  I guess a website form falls into this category.  It also appears that as part of this conversion some of the EXIF data disappears.

So, does anyone know a way to retain the EXIF data?  My primary limitation here is that the upload needs to happen through the webapp and that multiple users will be using this.  As a result, I can't simply have everyone change their iPhone settings to only shoot jpegs.

In case it matters, the webapp is running on node.js and expressjs.

Comment: I'm open to front-end and back-end options.  Of course a back-end option would probably require that we were able to upload as .heic in the first place.

Comment: Hi @reddisht, I'm currently fighting with exactly the same issue. I was just wondering if you had any luck with this?..

Comment: Have you tried to use the HTML attribute `accept` and enter reasonable mime-types for different HEIC/HEIF-formats to signal to the iPhone that those images are accepted? 

See this for the attribute: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/accept

See this for the mime types: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Efficiency_Image_File_Format